# How can I get the raw xml from an IXMLDOMNodeList in Microsoft Access?

Tags: xml, ms-access

How can I extract raw Xml text from an MSXML2 - IXMLDOMNodeList in Microsoft Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This query was posted for me by proxy.) The exact knowledge needed, is to take an MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList object returned by a web service api, and extract the data from the nodes. I have a piece of working code that does this for the XML version, but don't want to become a MSXML expert just to get one function to work. Here is the version that works with XML input, how do I change it to work with a nodeList input? (Can I also output the nodelist as XML? It would help with the remaining steps.

(added:)
 I have just tried the .xml property with nodes and that actually gives me the entire XML. Apparently, the api sends a nodelist, with a single node, and applying the .xml property to that single node yields an entire complete XMLdocument (which I can't figure out how to display here, the XML is processed in the preview).
( / added )

```
Private Sub ParseXML_Click()

Dim thisXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim fSuccess As Boolean
Dim oRoot     As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim oBooking  As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim oChildren As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim oChild    As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim theDB As Database
Dim theRST As Recordset

Set theDB = CurrentDb
Set theRST = theDB.OpenRecordset("XMLBookings", dbOpenDynaset)

Set thisXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
thisXML.async = False
thisXML.validateOnParse = False
fSuccess = thisXML.LoadXml(Bookings_fld)
 ' If anything went wrong, quit now.
If NotfSuccess Then
  GoTo ExitHere
End If

Set oRoot = thisXML.documentElement
For Each oBooking In oRoot.childNodes
    theRST.AddNew
    Set oChildren = oBooking.childNodes
    For Each oChild In oChildren
        Select Case oChild.nodeName
        Case "EventName"
'            MsgBox "EventName = " & oChild.nodeTypedValue
            theRST!EventName = oChild.nodeTypedValue
        Case 
        (etc)

        End Select
    Next oChild
        theRST.Update                         ' Save changes.
Next oBooking

MsgBox "Done!"
theRST.Close
Set theDB = Nothing

ExitHere:
        Exit Sub
HandleErr:
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Resume ExitHere
        Resume

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Xml property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms755989%28VS.85%29.aspx) on each IXmlDomNode.

Answer (score 0):

You'll do this with VBA.

Add the corresponding msxml dll to your tools

write some code like this one:

```
Public Function getFromXML(x_fileXML as string) as string

On Error GoTo ERREUR

      Dim doc_xml As MSXML2.DOMDocument, _
          list_xml As IXMLDOMNodeList, _ 
          i As Long, _
          m_getFromXML as string


Set doc_xml = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

doc_xml.Load x_fileXML

'i am interested by the nodeLists having a "attributeType: tag"'
Set list_xml = doc_xml.getElementsByTagName("s:AttributeType")
For i = 0 To (list_xml.Length - 1)
     'extract the requested data here'
     'something like m_getFromXML = m_getFromXML & ";" & ...'
Next i

getFromXML = m_getFromXML
```

This was written on the fly. Please check the objects to be closed/set to nothing before leaving the proc.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you plan to do with the xml. In access 2003, and 2007 we can import xml.

So, if you have a xml string that is a table of data, then you could receive the data, write out to disk, and then execute a Application.ImportXML. This approach is FAR less code then other answers given here.

Here is a code snip this concept:

```
Dim intF       As Integer
Dim strF       As String
Dim objXML     As Object

Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXML.Open "GET", "URL string here", False
objXML.Send

strF = "c:\t.xml"
intF = FreeFile
Open strF For Output As intF
Write #intF, objXML.responsetext
Close

Application.ImportXML "c:\t.xml", acAppendData
```

The above would assume that the XML has a catalog, or table def in the text

eg:

```
<CATALOG>
<tblContacts>
<ID>1</ID>
<Last_x0020_Name>Kallal</Last_x0020_Name>
<First_x0020_Name>Albert</First_x0020_Name>
</tblContacts>
<tblContacts>
<ID>2</ID>
<Last_x0020_Name>Smo</Last_x0020_Name>
<First_x0020_Name>Joe</First_x0020_Name>
</tblContacts>
</CATALOG>
```